# On Premise/High Trust app on SharePoint Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

Are high-trust (server-to-server) on-premise apps supported on SharePoint Foundation? I am guessing not, because:

- the User Profile Service is required for server-to-server/high-trust apps.
- the User Profile Service isn't available in Foundation, only Standard or Enterprise.

Are either of these assumptions wrong? Or can I use a high-trust app with SharePoint Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, SharePoint Foundation 2013 does not support the User profile Services as well as App Management Service Application which are mandatory pre requisite for the High trust app.