# Is it possible to develop a Provider hosted app for SharePoint Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I have SharePoint Foundation. Wanted to check if it is possible to build a provider hosted app without having an Azure subscription. I understand that high trust option is not possible since there is no User profile service on SharePoint Foundation. But my customer don't even have a O365 subscription, so cannot go with a low trust app. What are the other options?

Comment: If you are looking for long detailed answer, please refer to my [update](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/203743/2267)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provider hosted apps supported for SharePoint Foundation. Take a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise)
For building provider hosted app you don't need Azure or User profile service. For on-premise you can host your app anywhere you want (except SharePoint servers).

In high trust scenario your app will produce OAuth access tokens by using certificate. The only things needed for high trust are apps configured correctly and domain users.

**UPD**
In short, yes, it's possible to create provider hosted app for SP Foundation (**no** User Profile Service required).
Just to prove my point here the screencast video I've just created - http://www.screencast.com/t/53rrlwTy10T

**Ok, the long answer**

In high trust scenario the app itself produces OAuth token (that's why it's called **high** trust - the app is so trusted, that SharePoint also trusts to access tokens, generated by the app).

If you need to have an access to SharePoint resources via CSOM, you need to be authenticated inside SharePoint. This is possible via S2S OAuth flow (for online this is also OAuth, but with help of ACS). So you need OAuth access token. You can acquire it with helpful classes like `TokenHelper.cs` and `SharePointContext.cs`.

How does `TokenHelper.cs` work in case of high trust? It simply grabs user SID (unique domain security identifier), attaches it to list of claims and later generates access token. Two points are important here - your app generates access token and user SID is attached into the resulting access token (encoded).

Here are screenshots from TokenHelper when generating access token:

[image]

[image]

Then we attach this access token to request and we are good to go (authenticated). You see, in order to be authenticated in SharePoint, only user SID is required. You can grab it using many different way - with ADFS auth (ADFS sends SID claim), you can call .net method and get user SID by user name - `NTAccount f = new NTAccount("username");SecurityIdentifier s = (SecurityIdentifier) f.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));String sidString = s.ToString();`

All this auth options described here - [Plan for app authentication in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj219806.aspx#Anchor_2), part "Choose user authentication methods for on-premises apps"
Now we know how user gets authenticated in SharePoint.

What about this part - "Address User Profile application service considerations" [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj219806.aspx#Anchor_4):

> High-trust apps generate their own access tokens, which include an
>   assertion of the identity of the user on whose behalf they are acting

*assertion of the identity of the user* - that's our SID from screens above.
Did you see in SharePoint, when an item was created by the app, the created by is actually "created by `<App Name>` on behalf of `<User Name>`":

[image]

In order to extract this `<User Name>` SharePoint inspect incoming access token and extract user name. This process called *rehydrating the user’s identity*. Do you remember, we put SID right inside our access token. So the SharePoint can easily rehydrate the user by SID.
From the article you can also see, that not only SID can be used, but also AD DS UPN, SMTP name, SIP.

For SharePoint Enterprise, User Profile service is responsible for this process, that's why it's important to have it running. SharePoint Foundation also rehydrates user identity, but since there is no user profile, it uses other services for that purpose (I guess App Mng service). But that doesn't mean, that User Profile Service is required to make the app work in Foundation. In Foundation other services is responsible for rehydration.

**UPD2**
As I said, I did the project in the past without issues.

Now why I downvoted -
 *High-trust apps will need user profiles service app* - that's wrong, no user profile required, you can see the prove from my screencast above.

*You can do the development, but it's going to be limited, once you start doing the authentication part* - that's wrong, as I explained in my update, authentication is related to your app and can implemented in many various ways (and msdn article also proves that), it doesn't require user profile service at all, because your app authentication doesn't interfere with SharePoint services.

*and these limitations are regarding user profiles, which are needed for identity verification* - that's wrong, because like you just said Foundation uses Users List for rehydration.

*that doesn't mean it's the way to go to recommend it to someone* - where do you see I recommend something? I'm saying it's possible from my practice. All this assumptions about User Profile service is totally wrong. Also, just points to think - why does MS include developer site template for Foundation? Why there is a section "Apps: in Foundation under central admin?

*people out there are having issues when doing it on Foundation* do you know **exact** reason why the user getting 401? It doesn't mean that becasue of Foundation.

Comment: In the article you referenced, look at the column for the support, it says : "Yes1", which means it has limitations, and these limitations are regarding user profiles, which are needed for identity verification.

Comment: You are not correct, user profile is not required for identity verification for apps in SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: Read the documentation: High-trust apps need user profiles. How are you planning to do that in foundation?

Comment: Can you please provide a link, where they are saying that "High-trust apps need user profiles"?

Comment: Have a look at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj655398.aspx .. section: " To configure a SharePoint Server 2013 trust relationship with a high-trust app " :-)

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli: So you are saying it's not possible to use high trust apps for Foundation because of user profile service, right?

Comment: As per the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx  (Applies to SharePoint Server).. And https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shariq/2013/05/07/how-to-set-up-high-trust-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-troubleshooting-tips/

Comment: I would like to know the basis for saying my comment is wrong? Have any reference for configuring high-trust without user profiles?

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli: with all respect, simply because I did the project in the past without issues. You force me to load my old VM to show you a demo. Take a look here - http://www.screencast.com/t/53rrlwTy10T  while I'm preparing the long answer...

Comment: I would like to see, I will be more than glad to delete my own answer and vote yours up

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli: updated

Comment: It doesn't use other services to solve the identity as mentioned in your post, it uses user information list to grab user identity. You're going to face some issues with that approach, some I have already mentioned in the links I added, people out there are having issues when doing it on Foundation: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153953/iis-reset-causes-401-errors-on-high-trust-app/154508   .. you might not have faced, but that doesn't mean it's the way to go to recommend it to someone.

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli: see my next update

Comment: By the way, I never downvoted your post :-) I accept other opinions, and I would be open to learn anything. I don't know if you can check my voting history, but I never downvoted your post.

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli: I thought that's you :). I hope the others will find something useful from this active discussion :)

Comment: It's alright man

Comment: Thanks Kai and @MohamedDerhali for you responses... I tried creating a very basic high trust App on SP foundation, it seems to be working fine till now. Thanks Kai for the detailed explanation... Will update you guys in case I face any issues..

Answer (score 6):

High-trust apps will need user profiles service app, which is not available in SharePoint foundation.

Here's a similar case:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4fdee1a9-1493-4cd9-8166-4c90c27866c0/developing-provider-hosted-apps-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint

Planning for authentication:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj219806.aspx

Comment: Does that mean we cannot build provider hosted apps with SharePoint foundation?

Comment: You can do the development, but it's going to be limited, once you start doing the authentication part, you will need the user profiles.

Comment: In the link referenced by Kai, it says: Yes1, which means it's supported, but with limitations, which is basically the user profiles part. Some other posts I found a while back by Microsoft detail how to configure provider hosted add-ins, while mentioning SharePoint foundation at the top of their guidance, but they're using User Profiles in their configuration, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: `_once you start doing the authentication part, you will need the user profiles_` sorry, but that's not true.  You **can** create provider hosted app for foundation, but you can't use some client libraries' features, like interacting with user profiles, becasue there are no user profiles. This is the only limitation.

Comment: For ref. - consider "Applies to" header for the following msdn pages: [Plan for app authentication in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj219806.aspx), [Overview of apps for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161230.aspx), [Install and manage apps for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161232.aspx)

Comment: @Kai, What did I say, I said in my comment, you can create it with limitations, when it comes to user profile, which is the same comment you added to my post...

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli: that's what I'm saying.. your comment is not correct.

Comment: Take a look at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj655398.aspx  Microsoft's reference, ** To configure a SharePoint Server 2013 trust relationship with a high-trust app ** section